# Add extra meta for orders in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, orders

I'm creating a custom plugin for my website.

In some part of this plugin I need to store extra meta in `wp_postmeta` for each orders.

I added this in my plugin's class:

```
add_action ('woocommerce_before_checkout_process', array( &$this, 'add_item_meta', 10, 2) );
```

And this is `add_item_meta()` function:

```
function add_item_meta( $item_id, $values ) {
  wc_add_order_item_meta($item_id, '_has_event', 'yes' );
}
```

This function is not complete, but nothing happens with this codes; I think I need to use another hook but I can't find a proper one.

Does anyone know anything about this?

I also have another problem with `$item_id`: this is woocommerce global variable but I can't see it in my plugin!

I mean I don't have access to this variable from my plugin or something like this!

Answer (score 61):

**The 2018 way:**

Built on *Guido W.P.* answer you can use instead **`woocommerce_checkout_create_order`** action hook in
a more lighter and effective version code *(using [WC 3+ CRUD methods](https://woocommerce.com/2017/04/woocommerce-3-0-release/))*:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'before_checkout_create_order', 20, 2);
function before_checkout_create_order( $order, $data ) {
    $order->update_meta_data( '_custom_meta_key', 'value' );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

Tested and works in WooCommerce 3+ *(only)*.

---

**SOME EXPLANATIONS:**

The **`woocommerce_checkout_create_order`** action hook is just one step before saving the order data. See below in an **extract** of the `WC_Checkout` `create_order()` method (with both hooks):

```
/**
 * Action hook to adjust order before save.
 * @since 3.0.0
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', $order, $data );

// Save the order.
$order_id = $order->save();

do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', $order_id, $data );

return $order_id;
```

> **Why using `woocommerce_checkout_create_order` instead?**:
>
> - Because You don't need to use `$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );` as you already got **`$order`** as an argument in the hooked function.
> - You don't need to use `$order->save();` as this will be done just after anyway *(see the source code)*
> - This hook has been released since WooCommerce version 3 and it's made for the same purpose, allowing to use all available `WC_Order` methods.
>
> So this just works **with a single line of code** inside the function.

Comment: That's very clever @LoicTheAztec!
I have just one doubt: is it as future-proof as using `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta`?
It seems like `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta` was placed there by WooCommerce devs for the specific purpose of updating order meta.
I might be wrong, but using another filter for that specific purpose makes me a bit uncomfortable.

Comment: @GuidoWalterPettinari You can use in the same hooked function, code for different purposes, or have 2 different functions hooked in the same hook with different priorities… That is not a big deal :) … So both code works as well… The only difference is that **mine is just a bit lighter than yours** as I don't recall an instance of the WC_Order object and I don't need to use the save() method…

Comment: Hi Loic! I Your solution is indeed faster than mine, but I would not say that this is the only difference.
Based on the filter name, it is likely that the WooCommerce team wants us to update order meta using the filter `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta`.
My point is that it might be unwise to disregard that cue to gain a few milliseconds in execution time, especially because WooCommerce updates are so frequent and do not always respect backward compatibility.
I am a bit paranoid, I know 

Comment: @GuidoWalterPettinari I don't agree, because `woocommerce_checkout_create_order` **is maid for CRUD setters and getters** and has been released at the same time with WC 3… **Before CRUD setters and getters methods** *(so before WooCommerce 3)*, the only way was `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta` using `update_post_meta()` WP functions like… So no problem, I just offer here in my answer a good alternative regarding CRUD methods usage. That's all. No big deal…

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @LoicTheAztec!
It makes sense, let's hope the WooCommerce team clarifies this (small) issue at some point.
Have a nice day,
Guido

Answer (score 32):

Building on Mo Saeedi answer, I believe this snippet is more in line with the [new CRUD approach](https://woocommerce.com/2017/04/woocommerce-3-0-release/) introduced by WooCommerce 3.0:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta',function( $order_id, $posted ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $order->update_meta_data( 'my_custom_meta_key', 'my data' );
    $order->save();
} , 10, 2);
```

See also this threads on the WordPress forums:

- [Oh CRUD! Custom Meta to order from cart](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/oh-crud-custom-meta-to-order-from-cart/)
- [What is the correct way to update meta fields in Woocommerce?](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/what-is-the-correct-way-to-update-meta-fields-in-woocommerce/)

Comment: Thoughts on how to add a custom meta field (that is assigned to the Customer/User that ordered the item) to the order meta?

Comment: Please note that using closures for hooks is not good idea because you can't remove them later using `remove_action`.

Comment: Note you should use `new WC_Order($order_id);` these days instead of `wc_get_order`

Answer (score 6):

answer is:
I should use `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta` for add_action and also i should simply use `update_post_meta()` to add extra meta to my order

```
    function add_item_meta( $order_id ) {
            //global $woocommerce;
            update_post_meta( $order_id, '_has_event', 'yes' );
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

**The 2016 way:**

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta',function( $order_id, $posted ) {  
    update_post_meta( $order_id, 'my_custom_meta_key', 'my data' );  
} , 10, 2);
```

- `$order_id` is the id of the order, which is stored as a custom post type
- `$posted` is all the data from `$_POST`

Comment: Where is that code placed in the system?  In what file? Will this approach expose the custom data to the Order API call such as https://shop.example.com/wc-api/v3/orders/1248

Comment: You can place this code straight into your theme's `functions.php` file. WooCommerce will run the function just after the order is created and saved to the database.