# Show Queried Category Name In Woocommerce cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I Want to show product category name of woocommerce product in cart widget but category name should show display only one category name i.e  from which category archive product is added. 
 I added following code in functions.php but it shows all category name linked with product.

```
function modfuel_woocommerce_before_order_add_cat($name, $item){

   $product_id = $item['product_id'];

   $_product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
   $htmlStr = "";
   $cats = "";
   $terms = get_the_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat' );

   $count = 0;
   foreach ( $terms as $term) {
    $count++;

    if($count > 1){
      $cats .= $term->name;
    }
    else{
      $cats .= $term->name . ',';
    }

   }

   $cats = rtrim($cats,',');

   $htmlStr .= sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s </a>', esc_url( $prod_permalink ), $_product->get_name() );

   $htmlStr .= "
   <dl class='variation'><dt>Product Type:</dt><dd>" . $cats . "</dd></dl>";

   return $htmlStr;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_name','modfuel_woocommerce_before_order_add_cat', 10, 2);

add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_attribute_in_product_name', '__return_false' );
```

I want to add only queried category name in cart. I can achieve that it with following code but i dont know how can i display it in cart.

```
<?php 
    $queried_object = get_queried_object(); 
    echo $queried_object->name;
    ?>
```

Comment: Where on the cart widget do you want to display the queried category of the product ?

Comment: Along With Attribute / Variable Area

Comment: You should add the category name to the order meta data because the system won't remember what category you added the product from if you change pages.

Comment: how it can be done?

Comment: Plenty of articles on google. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25626058/add-extra-meta-for-orders-in-woocommerce