# Add custom checkout field as Order custom-meta data in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

before **WooCommerce 3.0** came out my code had worked like a charm to save custom values from the cart into the order on checkout. But since then I'm not able to create custom meta for orders.

**Environment:** Wordpress 4.9.4 & WooCommerce 3.3.3

### Hooks

1. `add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'custom_meta_to_order', 20, 1);`
2. `add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'custom_meta_to_order', 20, 1);`

The Hook number 1 is the one I tried the most, the 2 one was just an experiment with some literal [changes mentioned in this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48502896/1712681).

### Function

*The following functions-code is related to hook number 1*:

```
if (!function_exists('custom_meta_to_order')) {
    function custom_meta_to_order($order_id, $values) {
        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

        $order->update_meta_data('_TESTKEYstart', 'Hello');

        if (isset($values['myValue'])) {
            $myValue = $values['myValue'];
            if (!empty($myValue)) $order->update_meta_data('_myKey', $myValue);
        }

        $order->update_meta_data('_TESTKEYend', 'Bye');

        $order->save();
    }
}
```

I've checked also in the mySQL table `table wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta` if at least the two **_TESTKEY***-meta-entrys will be created (because they don't have a condition).

- But it seems that the meta-keys and values don't getting created via this hook and function.
- The function itself getting called, so at least the hooks itselfs are working.

### So my question is: "What am I doing wrong?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATED:** There is some errors in your code…

- Both hooks have only 1 argument (not 2, so `$values` doesn't exist)
- To get your custom field you should use `$_POST['myValue']` instead.
- and other things like each hook has a different argument:

  - `$order_id` for `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta`
  - `$order` for `woocommerce_checkout_create_order`

Below I have replaced `$_POST['myValue']` by `$_POST['billing_country']` as you don't give the code for this custom checkout field…

So here are both ways:

1) The best way for me, as explained [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25626058/add-extra-meta-for-orders-in-woocommerce/48502896#48502896):

```
if ( ! function_exists('custom_meta_to_order') ) {
    add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'custom_meta_to_order', 20, 1 );
    function custom_meta_to_order( $order ) {

        $order->update_meta_data('_TESTKEYstart', 'Hello');

        if (isset($_POST['billing_country'])) {
            $myValue = $_POST['billing_country'];
            if (!empty($myValue)) $order->update_meta_data('_my_key', $myValue);
        }

        $order->update_meta_data('_TESTKEYend', 'Bye');
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme)*. Tested and works.

---

2) The other way:

```
if ( ! function_exists('custom_meta_to_order') ) {
    add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'custom_meta_to_order', 20, 1);
    function custom_meta_to_order( $order_id ) {
        // get an instance of the WC_Order object
        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

        $order->update_meta_data('_TESTKEYstart', 'Hello');

        if (isset($_POST['billing_country'])) {
            $myValue = $_POST['billing_country'];
            if (!empty($myValue)) $order->update_meta_data('_my_key', $myValue);
        }

        $order->update_meta_data('_TESTKEYend', 'Bye');

        // Save the order data and meta data
        $order->save();
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme)*. Tested and works.

The proof:

[image]

And *(in database `wp_postmeta` table for this order ID)*:

[image]

> Tested in WooCommerce version 3.3+

---

You can use the old way too *(which works)*:

```
if ( ! function_exists('custom_meta_to_order') ) {
    add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'custom_meta_to_order', 20, 1);
    function custom_meta_to_order( $order_id ) {

        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_TESTKEYstart', 'Hello' );

        if ( isset( $_POST['billing_country'] ) ) {
            $myValue = $_POST['billing_country'];
            if (!empty($myValue)) 
                update_post_meta( $order_id, '_my_key', $myValue);
        }

        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_TESTKEYend', 'Bye');
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme)*. Tested and works.

---

Related: [Add extra meta for orders in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25626058/add-extra-meta-for-orders-in-woocommerce/48502896#48502896)

Comment: [Added an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49210098/1712681) instead of a comment, comment was in this case to short and restricted.

Answer (score 0):

**Because comments are really hard to read (because of to much restricted formatation), this answer is just a response to the [answer from LoicTheAztec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49019506/1712681).**

I wrote a longer answer but it seems gone, so I sorry now for the much shorter one!

**First our misunderstanding**

You understood that I would like to use custom values from products but in my case it was a little bit other. I wrote an external application which included the `wp-load.php` and posted then data back to the product-page into the cart.

So the problem showed up here was the attempt to write the data from the cart into the order on checkout.

**Recommend ways doesn't worked at first**

The recommend ways you suggested all doesn't worked. I also stripped them so much down that they have should work and just write something into the meta. I've no clue which plugin/theme-function pranked me this time here.

**But I was able to solve the problem**

And many more! Just because I found [the blog-post](https://wisdmlabs.com/blog/add-custom-data-woocommerce-order/) where I found out in the past, how to do this and as addition to my personal luck the author wrote already the [changes for WP3.0](https://wisdmlabs.com/blog/add-custom-data-woocommerce-order-2/), related to this process.

**Still your post helped me**

The errors you showed me bugged me since then and because it was hard to follow and inspect everything with Sublime and CodeIntel (and my start with Symfony itself) I decided to buy PHPStorm which showed and allowed me to fix all of my deprecated (legacy-using) functions by updating them properly.

( Finally no more global-variables: Yay. )

*I mean, showing up parameters inline and deprecation-strokes already did a great job. But a bug-free working code-intel/reference which doesn't dies on big projects is just awesome.*

That's why I marked your answer now as solution, thanks. Otherwise I would have just fixed the problem maybe (thanks to the authors blog-post) but still would sit on a ticking time bomb.