WooCommerce hook on save order - with request data ($_POST)
Wordpress 6.5, WooCommerce 8.7
I need hook on save, but with post data.
Hook woocommerce_store_api_checkout_update_order_meta doesn't works because of no rq data - $_POST is null.
Hook woocommerce_thankyou also doesn't have post data - $_POST is null.
My goal is to get custom added field by JS to the shipping form and save it to post_meta

you need woocommerce_checkout_create_order https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49019243/add-custom-checkout-field-as-order-custom-meta-data-in-woocommerce-3 or woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta

The answer is to add action: woocommerce_store_api_checkout_update_order_from_request
then you get as a second argument WP_REST_Request
