# How to add Custom Meta Data to a WooCommerce Order based on the Shipping Method

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm looking for a solution to add Custom Meta to each order in WooCommerce based on the shipping method chosen at the checkout. As far as I can see there have been some updates since WooCommerce 3.0 so I'm struggling to find a definitive answer to this.

Here's what I have so far.

According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25626058/add-extra-meta-for-orders-in-woocommerce) the WC3+ / CRUD method would be:

```
    add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'before_checkout_create_order', 20, 2);
function before_checkout_create_order( $order, $data ) {
    $order->update_meta_data( '_custom_meta_key', 'value' );
}
```

And according to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46102428/get-orders-shipping-method-details-in-woocommerce-3), you can use the shipping method conditionally using:

```
// Conditional function based on the Order shipping method 
if( $order->has_shipping_method('flat_rate') ) {
```

The problem I am having is combining these functions. Here's what I have tried but it doesn't seem to work:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'before_checkout_create_order', 20, 2);
function before_checkout_create_order( $order, $data ) {
    if( $order->has_shipping_method('Special Delivery') ) { 
    $order->update_meta_data( 'royal_mail_shipping_code', 'SD1' );
    }
    if( $order->has_shipping_method('Royal Mail Tracked 48') ) { 
    $order->update_meta_data( 'royal_mail_shipping_code', 'TPS' );
    }
}
```

Any help getting the above code working would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: When using `WC_Order` method `has_shipping_method()` you need to use **the Shipping Method ID** instead to get it working

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta',function( $order_id, $posted ) {

if( $order->has_shipping_method('Special Delivery') ) {
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
$order->update_meta_data( 'royal_mail_shipping_code', 'SD1' );
$order->save();
}
if( $order->has_shipping_method('Royal Mail Tracked 48') ) {
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
$order->update_meta_data( 'royal_mail_shipping_code', 'TPS' );
$order->save();
}
} , 10, 2);
```

Comment: Up until recently the following code was working, but it would seem the if statement now fails:

`add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'before_checkout_create_order', 20, 2);
function before_checkout_create_order( $order, $data ) {
    if( $order->has_shipping_method('table_rate:9') ) { 
    $order->update_meta_data( 'royal_mail_shipping_code', 'SD1' );
    }
 if( $order->has_shipping_method('table_rate:8') ) { 
    $order->update_meta_data( 'royal_mail_shipping_code', 'TPS48' );
    }
    else $order->update_meta_data( 'royal_mail_shipping_code', 'No Value' );
}`

Comment: Does anyone have any further guidence on this?

Comment: So far I have this code

`
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'before_checkout_create_order', 20, 2);
function before_checkout_create_order( $order, $data ) {
    
    if( $order->has_shipping_method('table_rate:9') ) { 
    $order->update_meta_data( 'royal_mail_shipping_code', 'SD1' );
    }
 if( $order->has_shipping_method('table_rate:8') ) { 
    $order->update_meta_data( 'royal_mail_shipping_code', 'TPS48' );
    }
    else $order->update_meta_data( 'royal_mail_shipping_code', 'No Value' );
}

`

Comment: The only bit of this that isn't working is the 

" if( $order->has_shipping_method('table_rate:9') )  "

The new method should use method_id & instance_id instead, but I can't figure out how to add this to the if statement