# Set Author for orders while creating at Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm creating custom multi vendor script in my website. I've set authors (vendors) for woocommerce products and I want to set authors for orders too so I can determine which vendor's product sold.

I'm programmatically creating amazon and other market's orders so I can't use woocommerce thankyou function.

Simply I want to ask, how to hook into woocommerce order save function both works in frontend and backend?

Answer (score 1):

- You can try `woocommerce_new_order` ([see](http://hookr.io/actions/woocommerce_new_order/)).
- You can also use order status based hooks, like `woocommerce_order_status_completed` or `woocommerce_order_status_changed`
- `woocommerce_checkout_create_order`, `woocommerce_checkout_create_order` or `woocommerce_payment_complete` would be for checkout actions only ([see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25626058/add-extra-meta-for-orders-in-woocommerce))

All those hooks have the Order or order_id as a parameter or the new order status.

Comment: does it fixes the issue?

Comment: Hi, actually its works. But I can't get the product id with that snipped:
`add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'set_author_for_order',  1, 1  );
function set_author_for_order( $order_id ) {
  global $woocommerce;
  $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
  foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_product ){
   $product_id = $item_product->get_product_id();
  }}`

Comment: can you dump the `$item_product` value and see what's in? The product ID may be as a an attribute on this object