# How to Grab and Update Order Meta?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to add the meta `Ready_by` to an order by taking the time set by `Order Due Date` and deducting an hour from it. This `Order Due Date` is set using the plugin [Order Delivery Date Pro](https://www.tychesoftwares.com/store/premium-plugins/order-delivery-date-for-woocommerce-pro-21/?utm_source=wprepo&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=OrderDeliveryDateLite), which adds a calendar date/time picker to checkout.

I've been trying between the hooks `woocommerce_checkout_create_order` and `woocommerce_thankyou` and couldn't get it work.

Here is the code I have so far in functions.php:

```
// Assign default ready by time by deducting an hour from the delivery due time
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'define_default_ready_by_time', 10, 1);

function define_default_ready_by_time( $order_id ) {
  $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

  $order_due_time = get_post_meta($order, 'Order Due Date', true);
  $ready_by_default = date('H:i',strtotime('-1 hour',strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime(str_replace('/','-',$order_due_time))))));

  $order->update_meta_data( 'Ready_by', $ready_by_default);
}
```

If anyone can shed a light on this, it'd be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

On this line

```
$order_due_time = get_post_meta($order, 'Order Due Date', true);
```

$order is an object where the post ID is required. [See here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/)
So you could use

```
$order_due_time = get_post_meta($order_id, 'Order Due Date', true);
```

Alternatively

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48502896/8472295) gives a more in depth description, but the following code should work.

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'before_checkout_create_order', 20, 2);
function before_checkout_create_order( $order, $data ) {

    $order_due_time = $order->get_meta('_order_due_date'); //better way to get order meta

    //I'm unsure if this works from your code, need to test it, but assuming it does
    $ready_by_default = date('H:i',strtotime('-1 hour',strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime(str_replace('/','-',$order_due_time))))));


    $order->update_meta_data( '_order_due_date', $ready_by_default  );
}
```