# Save WooCommerce order item custom fields sum as a new meta data

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

When a particular product is ordered in this WooCommerce store, two meta values are added to the order.

The two fields that store the meta values are located in `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta`

The meta keys are :

```
quantity
assemblycost
```

I want to create a new custom field programmatically when a new order is placed and set the value of this new field equal to `quanity * assemblycost` if the meta key assemblycost exists for the product that has been ordered.

After some research I discovered that `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta` is a hook that is executed after an order is saved to the database and the meta data has been updated. So this appears to be the hook I should use.

Ref: 
[Add extra meta for orders in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25626058/add-extra-meta-for-orders-in-woocommerce) :

```
 function add_item_meta( $order_id ) {
            //global $woocommerce;
            update_post_meta( $order_id, '_has_event', 'yes' );
        }
```

I tried adding the following code, in functions.php:

```
 add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta',function( $order_id, $posted ) {  
    $assemblycost = wc_get_order_item_meta($order_id, 'assemblycost');
    $quantity = wc_get_order_item_meta($order_id, 'quantity');
    $calculatedValue = $quantity * $assemblycost;
    wc_update_order_item_meta( $order_id, 'calculated_field', $calculatedValue );  
} , 10, 2);
```

This does create the new meta field, however it sets the value to 0.

[image]

How can I change the code above so that the value of calculated_field is the multiplication of `quantity * assemblycost` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is related to **order items** and should be saved as order item meta data but not as order meta data.

Now this should be saved **at the same time** than your 2 custom fields `quantity` and `assemblycost`. So you should provide in your question the related code that save `quantity` and `assemblycost` as order item meta data.

You can try the following (but I am not sure that I will work):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'action_checkout_create_order_line_item_callback', 1000, 4 );
function action_checkout_create_order_line_item_callback( $item, $cart_item_key, $cart_item, $order ) {
    $quantity     = $item->get_meta('quantity');
    $assemblycost = $item->get_meta('assemblycost');
    if( isset($quantity) && isset($assemblycost) ) {
        $item->update_meta_data( 'calculated_field', $quantity * $assemblycost );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

Comment: That worked great. I have one follow up question. This adds a custom field 'calculated_field' for each product ordered, in the order. Would you happen to know how I can add one further custom field to the entire order, that is the sum of all the 'calculated_field's in the order? e.g. product A in the order, calculated_field value is 25, product B in the order, calculated_field value is 50. Then this additional custom field for the entire order should be 50+25 = 75. Thank you.

Comment: @Gary Please ask a new question with it… once done notify me and I will answer it.

Comment: @LociTheAztec great thank you - here is the follow up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55879116/how-to-create-an-order-custom-field-for-a-woocommerce-order-that-auto-populates