# Save the sum of all specific order item custom fields as order meta data in WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, metadata, hook-woocommerce, orders

Following my previous question *" 
[Save WooCommerce order item custom fields sum as a new meta data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55878479/save-woocommerce-order-item-custom-fields-sum-as-a-new-meta-data)"*, when an order is placed, some order item custom meta data `quantity`, `assemblycost` and `calculated_field` *(which value is to `quantity` x `assemblycost`)* are saved.

How can I save as custom order meta data the sum of all order items `calculated_field` values?

For example, a sample order would look like so:

```
Product A:
assemblycost: 10
quantity: 2
calculated_field: 20

Product B:
assemblycost: 15
quantity: 2
calculated_field: 30

Product C: 
no assemblycost, quanity or calculated_field - custom fields present. 

Product D: 
assemblycost: 30
quantity: 2
calculated_field: 60
```

I want to create a new custom field for the order `sum_calculated_fields` , and set this equal to the sum of the `calculated_fields` in the order, so in the above example it would equal:

20+30+60 = 110.

Comment: There was a mistake in my code that I have updated just now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated:** Here is the way to sum all the order item `calculated_fields` custom field and save that sum as custom order meta data:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'action_checkout_create_order_callback', 10, 2 );
function action_checkout_create_order_callback( $order, $data ) {
    $calculated_fields_sum = 0; // Initializing

    // Loop Through order items
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        if( $value = $item->get_meta('calculated_field') ) {
            $calculated_fields_sum += $value;
        }
    }
    // Update order meta data
    if( $calculated_fields_sum > 0 ) {
        $order->update_meta_data( 'calculated_fields_sum', $calculated_fields_sum );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should work.